# mod_rewrite as 404 handler

Tags: mod-rewrite

im trying to make mod_rewrite work as a 404 handler

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              http://www.domain.com/error.php [L]
```

but in some cases if you request an url with no "file names" it also rewrites to the error.php

eg

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/dir/
```

Comment: why are you trying to impose that restriction? Why is `ErrorDocument` not enough? Besides, this belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you could use [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) in .htaccess, but if you like me needed at some point to display custom 404 for several domains/languages using the same codebase (same unique .htaccess file), I suggest adding one ErrorDocument directive on a per vhost basis instead.

Comment: I only have one vhost (wild card) for all my domains.. How can I then handle this?